# How to use viewmodel and I want to use mic functionality code in drffrent class?

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel

```
Main Activity code public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FrameLayout z;
    NavController navController;
    private SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;
    private SpeechRecognitionUtility speechRecognitionUtility;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main);

        sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        speechRecognitionUtility = new SpeechRecognitionUtility ((SpeechRecognitionCallback) sharedViewModel); // This line cased app crash

    }


}
Main Activity xml `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_z" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`
fragment z code `public class Z extends Fragment {

    private TextView edit;
    private ImageView google;
    private ImageView mic;
    private SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;

    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_z, container, false);


        sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);

        edit = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtsearch_first);
        google = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_google_first);
        mic = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_mic);




        edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_z_to_y);
            }
        });

        google.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_z_to_y);
            }
        });




        return rootView;
    }

}

`
fragment z xml`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/Fristsearch_bar"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_design">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_google_first"
            android:layout_width="46dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:src="@drawable/google"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="MIC"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edtsearch_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/img_mic"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img_google_first"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/enter_text_or_url"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#83827D"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,VisualLintTextFieldSize" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_mic"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_mic_24"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:contentDescription="@string/mic" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>` 

fragment y code `public class y extends Fragment {

    public static final int SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
    private EditText edtSearch;
    private LinearLayout boxOne;
    private LinearLayout boxTwo;
    private SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;
    private SpeechRecognitionUtility speechRecognitionUtility;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_y, container, false);


        edtSearch = rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt_search);
        ImageView imgMic = rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_mic);
        ImageView imgSearch = rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_search);
        ImageView clearText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.clear_text);
        TextView closeBar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.close_bar);
        boxOne = rootView.findViewById(R.id.box_one);
        boxTwo = rootView.findViewById(R.id.box_two);

        closeBar.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            edtSearch.setText("");

            if (getActivity() != null) {
              
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

                fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
        }); 
        imgMic.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        
            startVoiceInput();
        });
   return rootView;
    }
 private void startVoiceInput() {
         
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
          
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Speech recognition is not available.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                    String spokenText = result.get(0);
                    edtSearch.setText(spokenText);
                }
            }

        }







}
```

I want to when user click mic button in searchbar then (where fragment layout z mic button click or fragment z mic button click ) spoken text set on edtsearch (Edit Text) in fragment layout y.I already create ViewModel class and mic initialization code class. But i don't know how to use it because when i use Viewmodel and mic initialization function code then app crashing. How to fix it.